Change border color of TextField on focused
I have a Dialog  that receives a set of colors through props. According to this set of colors I need to set a border color for my Material UI TextField, but I can't get it to work.
I have this makeStyles:
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
          borderColor: ({colors}) => `${colors ? colors.greenAccent[600] : "white"}`,
        },
      },
    },
  })
);

And this is my TextField
    <TextField
      style={{ marginLeft: "4px", marginTop: "8px", color:  colors ? colors.grey[200] : "white"}}
      className={classes.root}
      label="Valor da meta"
      variant="outlined"
      name="valor_meta"
      id="valor_meta"
      InputLabelProps={{
        style: { 
          color: colors ? colors.grey[200] : "white",
         }
      }}

      value={valorMeta}
      onChange={(e) => {
        const inputValue = e.target.value;
        if (/^[0-9.,]*$/.test(inputValue)) {
          if (
            inputValue.indexOf(".") === inputValue.lastIndexOf(".") &&
            inputValue.indexOf(",") === inputValue.lastIndexOf(",")
          ) {
            if (
              !(inputValue.includes(",") && inputValue.includes("."))
            ) {
              setValorMeta(inputValue);
            }
          }
        }
      }}
    />

This is the complete code of my Dialog component:
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root': {
        '&.Mui-focused fieldset': {
          borderColor: ({colors}) => `${colors ? colors.greenAccent[600] : "white"}`,
        },
      },
    },
  })
);

const DialogMeta = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  const [valorMeta, setValorMeta] = useState("");
  const [idTipoMeta, setIdTipoMeta] = useState(0);
  const [textoTipoMeta, setTextoTipoMeta] = useState("");
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.colors) {
      setColors(props.colors);
    }
}, [props.color]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    props.callbackNao();
  };

  const handleSim = () => {
    if (!valorMeta) {
      toast.error("Preencha um valor para a meta", { theme: "colored" });
      return;
    }
    if (!textoTipoMeta || textoTipoMeta === "Sem tipo") {
      toast.error("Selecione um tipo para a meta", { theme: "colored" });
      return;
    }
    props.callbackSim({ valorMeta, textoTipoMeta });
  };

  return (
    <Dialog
      open={props.mostrar}
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-title"
      aria-describedby="alert-dialog-description"
      maxWidth="md"
      fullWidth
    >
      <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-title">{props.titulo}</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent>
        <center>
          <DialogContentText
            id="alert-dialog-description"
            style={{ maxHeight: "50%", overflowY: "auto" }}
          >
            Digite o valor e o tipo que deseja para a meta
          </DialogContentText>

          <div
            style={{
              display: "flex",
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center",
            }}
          >

            <TextField
              style={{ marginLeft: "4px", marginTop: "8px", color:  colors ? colors.grey[200] : "white", borderColor: colors ? colors.greenAccent[600] : "white"}}
              className={classes.root}
              label="Valor da meta"
              variant="outlined"
              name="valor_meta"
              id="valor_meta"
              InputLabelProps={{
                style: { 
                  color: colors ? colors.grey[200] : "white",
                 }
              }}

              value={valorMeta}
              onChange={(e) => {
                const inputValue = e.target.value;
                if (/^[0-9.,]*$/.test(inputValue)) {
                  if (
                    inputValue.indexOf(".") === inputValue.lastIndexOf(".") &&
                    inputValue.indexOf(",") === inputValue.lastIndexOf(",")
                  ) {
                    if (
                      !(inputValue.includes(",") && inputValue.includes("."))
                    ) {
                      setValorMeta(inputValue);
                    }
                  }
                }
              }}
            />

            <SelectTipoMeta
              name="supervisor"
              colors={colors}
              id_meta={idTipoMeta}
              onSelected={(tipo) => {
                setIdTipoMeta(tipo.id);
                setTextoTipoMeta(tipo.nome);
              }}
            />
          </div>
        </center>
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
          {props.textoNao}
        </Button>
        {props.callbackSim ? (
          <Button onClick={handleSim} color="primary" autoFocus>
            {props.textoSim}
          </Button>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default DialogMeta;

When I open the Dialog the border color remains the default color when focused, but if I save the Dialog file the correct color is applied to the border. How can I make it work without this save issue?

After saving, the focus is no longer in the textfield right? The color is on its default only when the focus is on the input?

The default color is a dark blue. So when I open the dialog and click on the TextField it gets e dark blue border color. If I return to the code file, save and click on TextField again it gets the colors.greenAccent[600] that I wanted.

Can you provide the other code like the saving part?

I updated the post with the complete code
